# Filter user in django and add to a existing group

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am new to Django and I have failing on a task now for a while. I have searched in the Django docs and here for some questions but there nothing is working for me.

Here is my view:

```
  def user_accept(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
        username = AddUser.objects.filter(owner=request.user).get().user_request
        group_name = Projects.objects.filter(user=request.user).get().group_url
        group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
        group.user_set.add(username)
        delete_user = AddUser.objects.filter(user_request=username)
        delete_user.delete()
```

Here is my model:

```
class AddUser(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', blank=True)
    user_request = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    answer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**AddUser** model is used for users to request access to a specific project. So when a user is requesting a project, data is saved to the AddUser model. 
The user field is set to the "owner" of the project so I can filter every project with a proper owner.

If the owner decides to accept the request my user_accept view is executed. Here is the problem, when I try to add the username into the group, I get the following error:

> ```
> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'myusername'
> ```

I have tried to convert the username with int(username) and tried to get the username's user_id but nothing seems to work... I think it have something to do how I filter my objects but I don't get it.

So thanks a lot for your time, and have a happy new year!

Comment: what type of field is user_set in group table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the user id or the user object itself to add a user with `group.user_set.add`.

You can either retrieve the user object from the username, provided usernames are unique and add that:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=user_request)
group.user_set.add(user)
```

Or change your `AddUser` model to store the requester's id via a *OneToOne* field or *ForeignKey* instead of username.

Comment: Hi! It worked!! Thank you, so stupid of me, never thought of that... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Django default groups doesn't allow you to add username into it. 
You have to add User objects.
Try

```
add_user_object = AddUser.objects.filter(owner=request.user).get()
group.user_set.add(add_user_object.owner)
```